# In C++17, does being non-decreasing necessarily imply being sorted, even when using a comparator that is NOT a total order?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge, stl

In C++17 (standard ISO/IEC 14882:2017(E)), the terms **sorted** and **non-decreasing** are NOT identical:

A sequence `[first, last)` is said to be in ***non-decreasing*** order with respect to a comparator `comp` if for any iterator `it` in `[first, last)` other than `first`, the condition `comp(*it, *(it - 1))` (i.e. `*it < *(it - 1)`) evaluates to `false`. (see ISO/IEC 14882:2017(E) 28.7.5 p. 1035)

Note that *non-decreasing* is NOT defined as: "Whenever iterators `it` and `it + 1` are in `[first, last)` then `*it <= *(it + 1)`" (the operator <= need not even be defined; ditto for `operator==`).

A sequence is said to be ***sorted*** with respect to a comparator `comp` if for any iterator `it` pointing to the sequence and any non-negative integer `n` such that `it + n` is a valid iterator pointing to an element of the sequence, `comp(*(it + n), *it)` evaluates to `false`. (see ISO/IEC 14882:2017(E) 28.7 p. 1028)

Note that *sorted* is NOT defined as: "Whenever iterators `it` and `it + 1` are in `[first, last)` then `*(it + 1) < *it` evaluates to false."

Clearly, if a range is sorted then it is non-decreasing. **IF** the comparator `comp` is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) then it's easy to see that if a range is non-decreasing with respect to `comp` then it is sorted with respect to `comp`. But if `comp` isn't a total order then is it still necessarily true that if a range is *non-decreasing* with respect to `comp` then it is *sorted* with respect to `comp`?

Note that the only requirements on `comp` are that it satisfy the Compare requirements: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare .
In particular, `comp` is *not* required to be a total order (however, the induced equivalence classes described on that page will form a total order under the order the *induced* by `comp`).

***Why this question is important:***

I don't have a counter example but I suspect that the answer is no since why else would the standard distinguish the terms *sorted* and *non-increasing*? (UPDATE: The answer is ***yes***). For instance, with [`std::inpace_merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until), the two input ranged are required to be *sorted* but the output range is merely required to be *non-decreasing* (the standard does NOT say that the output range of `std::inpace_merge()` must be sorted).

The reason that I'm asking is because if this is NOT true then there would appear to be a problem with many STL implementations of many `std` algorithms.

Note that [`std::is_sorted_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted_until) is implemented the same way in both [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L3211) and [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/a12cb9d211019d99b5875b6d8034617cbc24c2cc/include/algorithm#L3614); they are essentially this:

```
template <class ForwardIt, class Compare>
ForwardIt is_sorted_until(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp) 
{
    if (first != last) {
        ForwardIt next = first;
        while (++next != last) {
            if (comp(*next, *first))
                return next;
            first = next;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

Notice the problem? These implementations of `std::is_sorted_until()` **find the longest *non-decreasing* range rather than finding the longest *sorted* range.** The standard requires of `std::is_sorted_until(first, last)` that (ISO/IEC 14882:2017(E) 28.7.1 p. 1031):

> If `(last - first) < 2` returns `last`. Otherwise, returns the last
>   iterator `i` in `[first, last)` for which the range `[first, i)` is
>   sorted.

So if in the general case, a range being *non-decreasing* does NOT necessarily imply that the range is *sorted* then these implementations do not adhere to the standard. This would have downstream effects.

For instance, the standard basically states that [`std::is_sorted()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) should be defined as:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class Compare>
bool is_sorted(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp)
{
    return std::is_sorted_until(first, last, comp) == last;
}
```

This means that `std::is_sorted()` also checks the definition of a *non-decreasing* range rather than checking the definition of a *sorted* range.

Now what requirements are made of the output of [`std::merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) in the standard? Well if the output range is `[d_first, d_last)` then the standard's requirement is that the "range satisfies `std::is_sorted(d_first, d_last)` or `std::is_sorted(d_first, d_last, comp)`, respectively." (ISO/IEC 14882:2017(E) 28.7.5 p. 1035)

This is why it's important to know the answer to this question. (Also, this would help me with some algorithms I'm trying to test).

Comment: If the comparator is transitive, then non-decreasing implies sorted; it doesn't have to be a total order. If the comparator is not transitive then non-decreasing does not imply sorted.

Comment: @kaya3 Every comparator is required to be a strict weak ordering, which means that every `comp` is required to be transitive. Do you have a reference for this? Where the terms "non-decreasing" and "sorted" are defined as in the C++17 ISO standard? (Note that "non-decreasing" is NOT defined as "*it <= *(it + 1)" or anything like that).

Comment: I see; then it is still true, but for the complement of the comparator (i.e. the opposite, it returns true if and only if the original comparator returns false). It is a theorem that the complement of a strict weak ordering is a total pre-order, which is necessarily transitive, so as far as I can tell, if `comp` is indeed a strict weak ordering then non-decreasing does imply sorted. I don't have a reference for C++ specifically, but here's Wikipedia: *"The complement of a strict weak order is a total preorder, and vice versa"* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the complement of the comparator, i.e. a function which returns the opposite boolean result `!comp(x, y)`:

1. If the sequence is **non-decreasing**, then `comp(*it, *(it - 1))` is always false.
2. So, `!comp(*it, *(it - 1))` is always true.
3. If `!comp` is transitive, then it follows that `!comp(*(it + n), *it)` is also always true.
4. In that case, `comp(*(it + n), *it)` is always false, so the sequence is **sorted**.

The comparator `comp(x, y)` is required to be a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). It is a mathematical theorem that *"The complement of a strict weak order is a total preorder"* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders)), and total pre-orders are transitive, so the required property of `!comp` holds in step 3. of the proof above.

Therefore, for a valid comparator meeting the requirement of being a strict weak ordering, the conditions of being non-decreasing and of being sorted are logically equivalent; therefore the STL implementations of `is_sorted` (which only check adjacent elements) are correct.

Comment: An example is needed. If `comp` (I'll use `<` for brevity)  defined by a strict weak ordering on {`a`,`b`,`c`} where `a<c` and `b<c` but neither `a<b` nor `b<a` and you have an iterator `it`, the sequence is "sorted" if `*it == a && *(++it) == b` **but also** if `*it == b && *(++it) == a` !